# Why does RedirectToAction have no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

When the method with the barcode parameter is called, RedirectToAction has absolutely no effect. I can see that it does indeed return to that route in the URL, but the model is not refreshed and it displays stale data.

In the SQL Server profiler I can see that the call isn't being made to pull back the new data.

How can I force this to happen?

Incidently, the call to: `public ActionResult SRScanItem(string barcode)` is itself the result of a RedirectToAction from another controller.

I have handful of calls to `RedirectToAction("SRPickCollectionItems")` elsewhere in the same controller and these all work fine.

Any idea what may be causing this?

```
public ActionResult SRPickCollectionItems()
{
    IEnumerable<ISRPickingItemSummary> items = 
        SRPickingItemsViewModel.
        GetDisplayableChunk(ApplicationState.CollectionId.ToString(),
                            ApplicationState.AssistantNumber);

    return View(items);            
}

public ActionResult SRScanItem(string barcode)
{
    DataLayer.Instance.AddStockroomFoundItem(barcode, ApplicationState.CollectionId, ApplicationState.AssistantNumber);
    return RedirectToAction("SRPickCollectionItems");   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the redirect is going to a cached page.

Could you try and decorate SRPickCollectionItems with

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to returning to a post method, only a get so it is not obvious how the method with the Redirect is getting called unless you are send the barcode as a query string parameter in a get call through an actionlink or link tag.

Normally you would have two methods named SRPickCollectionItems. The Get method (which you already have) loads the view and the post method (that you are missing) processes the postback. The post method would be thus...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SRPickCollectionItemsstring barcode){
    DataLayer.Instance.AddStockroomFoundItem(barcode, ApplicationState.CollectionId,              ApplicationState.AssistantNumber);
    return RedirectToAction("SRPickCollectionItems");   
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. I've seen that [HttpPost] decoration on various bits of code I've seen but was never sure when and where to use them.